# Map a region of file into MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I want to load a big TXT file into more than one MappedByteBuffer Using Map method.

Then i want to search into those Buffer for specific word.

so is there any way to Guarantee That i don't divide at the middle of any word

so the split must be on white space or end of the line?

Comment: Only if the file has fixed length lines. I think you'll find that BufferedReader.readLine() is more than fast enough for your needs.

Comment: No the file has not fixed length lines

Comment: so readline() is the only way ??in my situation?

Comment: I didn't say it was the only way, I said it was probably a perfectly adequate way. It's also really easy to implement. I suggest you try it and determine whether you really do have an I/O performance problem.

Comment: but i have around 200MB txt file so how i can divide it equally to fixed number of parts using readline?

Comment: You can read a file that size from start to finish in a few seconds. I don't see why you need to partition it at all

Comment: You can map 200 MB as a single region easily, even in a 32-bit JVM.  You can't guarantee you won't split a word unless you read the file first to find where the word boundaries are, instead you should write code so it doesn't matter if you do.

Comment: @EJP I want to partition my file because i want to process it on parallel using JPVM for learning purpose

Comment: umm, in the partition logic, id hit the middle character, and as long as it is not blank id keep reading characters moving left or right, when i find a blank id partition at that point. I'm sure this will be slower.